# How to fetch & update data each midnight on ios (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that is using a method for fetching data from web server each time it launches.
The data is fetched only if there was an update in the remote data.

**Is there a way for the app to run the fetch method each midnight?**

Comment: In iOS, there is no way to run a method every midnight. The closest thing that iOS has is background fetch, which Igor discussed, but that's run at a time that the OS chooses, not according to some predetermined schedule. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31577935/1271826 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30944715/1271826

Comment: You can use Silent notification using silent notification you can do even app is in not running mode. it will automatically activate your app and you can fetch data when you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add this notification

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.fetchData), name: NSCalendarDayChangedNotification, object: nil)
```

However, note that your app is sandboxed, so you can't expect this notification to be posted if the app is not active. However, according to the documentation

> If the the device is asleep when the day changes, this notification will be posted on wakeup. Only one notification will be posted on wakeup if the device has been asleep for multiple days.

So at least you know this is a guaranteed call everyday.

Comment: This was an iOS question. But this looks like a macOS answer. This is not relevant on iOS.

Comment: @Rob, this is what I did for my Social Network app for iOS, I've never developed in macOS before. Sorry

Comment: OK. I inferred too much from the "if your app is sandboxed" comment, because all iOS apps are sandboxed. The bottom line is that this will, for all practical purposes, not do anything until the user fires up the app next time. I guess I'm not seeing how this addresses the OP's question.

Comment: Unless the OP really 100000% needs the data fetched at 12, else I think my solution is alright.

Comment: How's that? If the user doesn't fire up the app for a week, nothing happens for a week, right? I don't think that's the OP's intent. It's trivial to retrieve data when the user starts the app. (He's already doing that, no notifications needed for that.) He presumably wants to retrieve data even when the user doesn't explicitly fire up the app.

Answer (score 1):

Background Fetch API created special for this. You can learn about it in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) or [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/)